# Caching debounced functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, memoization, debouncing

I'm trying to create a function wrapper that can be called with a DOM element as an argument and will return a unique debounced function tied to that DOM element that has some logic in it.

I will clarify my thought process, step by step:

### Here is the original debounced function

```
hideElementWhenIdle = _.debounce(($el) => {
  if($el.is(":hover"))
    hideElementWhenIdle($el);
  else
    $el.removeClass("visible");
}, 5000);
```

Now, this function worked perfectly fine, until I realized that I was tying the debounced function to the first element it was called with. So, if I wanted to create:

```
hideElementWhenIdle( $("selector-1") );
hideElementWhenIdle( $("selector-2") );
```

they would basically debounce each other. What I wanted were unique functions for each element.

### Dirty solution

Of course I could do something like this:

```
hideElementWhenIdle = function($el) {
  let fn = _.debounce(($el) => {
    // ... same as above
  }, 5000);
  
  return fn;
}

hideSelector1WhenIdle = hideElementWhenIdle( $("selector-1") );
hideSelector2WhenIdle = hideElementWhenIdle( $("selector-2") );
```

Now I would have two independent functions that I can call. However, this is obviously dirty and non-scalable (though, to be fair, I only have two elements that I need to apply to function to anyways).

### Failing attempt

I thought I could `wrap` and `memoize` my function to achieve what I wanted to do, but after trying several attempts, I can't wrap my head around what's going on (or if it's even the right solution). Here is my latest attempt:

```
var hideElementWhenIdle = _.wrap(
  _.memoize( 
    function($el) {
      var fn = _.debounce(() => {
        // ... same as above
      }
    ),
  function(func, $el) {
    return func($el);
  }
);
```

I am guessing that my problem here is that `_.debounce` always returns the same value, so I am always caching the same value regardless of `$el`.

Comment: the *dirty solution* is quite clean and robust in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

Your *dirty* solution is the way to go in my opinion. Or you need your own debouncer:

```
function debounce(func,time){
   var debouncing=new Map();
   return function(el){
        if(!debouncing.get(el)){
            debouncing.set(el,setTimeout(_=>debouncing.set(el,null),time));
            return func(el);
        }
    };
}
```

usecase:

```
var func=debounce(function(el){
   $el=$(el);
   if($el.is(":hover"))
      hideElementWhenIdle($el);
   else
     $el.removeClass("visible");
 }, 5000);

func("#sth");
func("#sth");//debounced
func("#sthelse");//not debounced
```

Note: this wont work with passing jquery objects as theyre unique. DOM nodes will work.

http://jsbin.com/bujocoravu/1/edit?js

Comment: Mm… thanks for your reply. The problem with the dirty solution is that it totally doesn't scale as I keep adding elements. I didn't try your debounced function, but it looks like it might do the trick. Although I'd rather not write the whole `debounce` again since I'm using lodash implementation. I think the setting of maps is exactly what `memoize` does, and that's why I am trying to go that route. Any suggestions on that and why it is not working? Perhaps for the same reason as you said, I should pass DOM nodes?

Comment: @sunyatasattva you need a mixin of both, and a 5 liner is probably more lightweight then lodash